# pushsharp newbie-web app developer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webforms, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, pushsharp

I need to create a push notification service in my web app, and also in my app. I want to use pushsharp 4.0, but have no idea where to begin. Do I need to create a Web service, a Windows service? My web app is webforms with Visual Studio 2013. And the mobile app is being developed for Android and Windows pone 8.1.

Any help on tutorials or samples for newbies much appreciated.

Comment: have you googled the subject?

Comment: Lots!!! Haven't found something that can help get me started. In here I have found a lot of advanced questions. But nothing as basic as how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. There is a lot of things you need to do so push notifications work. After doing this list I'm posting, it Works like a charm.

This list is for cloud service not hosted in azure
1. Register your Windows app to get a Windows store package Name and SID

2. Update your Package.appxmanifest file with the package name and sid
3. Get a secret password at developer.microsoft.com
4. Create a web service to authenticate your cloud service
5. Enable your app to recive toast in your package manifest file
6. Use Windows.Networking.PushNotifications namespace
7. In your web service you must create the following variable:
   Dim wnsConfig As new WnsConfiguration("your package name", "your SID", "your Secret Password"

That's it